# What should be the status code if the value is not present in DB against the particular column?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have put API which will modify user city based on user name.`'api/v1/user/modify_city'` . In request body i have input JSON.

```
{
  'name':'Jhon',
   'city': 'NY'
}
```

I want to modify city to be 'NY' against 'Jhon' user name but user name jhon is not exist in DB , so in this case what should i return the status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard HTTP status code is 404 in this case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Some projects use different conventions, in which case local convention must have precedence.